# Lock folder and all its contents such that it is temporarily read-only

Tags: macos, filesystem

I want to lock a folder from modification, which includes all its contents. I thought that this could be accomplished with the "Get Info" window and selecting the "Locked" checkbox, but this does not affect the contents of the folder.

I am on an iMac running macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open Terminal
- `cd to/folder`
- `chmod -R a-w .`

To undo run `chmod -R u+w .` instead.

The first command recursively removes wrote access from all users, the second gives write access to the current user (because that‘s what is the default anyway).

Comment: Any chance you can explain the command? I'm not a huge fan of using something I do not understand

Comment: @grahamcracker1234 See update

Answer (score 0):

Easier way without commands: [here is LapTopMag's article on how to](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/password-protect-folder-mac).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.